# Why are some scope variables in Chrome Dev Tools greyed out (light purple)?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Why are some scope variables in Chrome Dev Tools greyed out (light purple)?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools - Scope Variables]

Comment: I want to point out the accepted answer is wrong. try ```
window.chrome.propertyIsEnumerable('webstore')
``` and you will get `true`, but window.chrome.webstore is light purple. ![console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cVt7.png) Click the (...)invoke property getter can make the color become dark purple, so there are two reasons for light purple color.

Comment: Hard to differ with the author of the question that answered his own question and so many have upvoted...

Comment: `window.chrome.propertyIsEnumerable('webstore')` returns false though......

Comment: Can you update the original answer with your discovery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that the greyed out variables are not enumerable. While paused on a breakpoint run `greyedOutVariableName.propertyIsEnumerable('propertyName')` and it should return false.

[Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)

Thanks to ckocagil on #chromium-support on Freenode for this!